# How can I add admin comments to webform submissions?

Tags: webforms, workflows, 9

First time question, apologies for any mistakes.

I'm using the workflow module maestro, and in combination with webform i am attempting to add a section to show admin level comments as part of a moderation workflow.

I haven't attempted much yet but could use some suggestions on how best to achieve this?

I could make the webform a node and attach a comment block with permission controls, i could write a custom maestro module and add a custom task to achieve this also.

Comment: What is the workflow for adding/showing comments that you want to achieve?

Comment: Ideally looking to, have a webform submission shown

Then a task in maestro showing the submission and allowing the admin to comment on the form with accept/reject buttons

So a workflow could look like
- User submits registration webform
- admin approves/denies (leaves a comment)
- notification of approval/denial sent to the user

Comment: Opinion-based. I once build something similar by adding reject/approve entity operations for the submissions. Which when triggered opened a small modal form and then saved the comments and status in elements added to the webform which where hidden for everybody else. Email notifications can be done with webform handlers. You can do that from the webform UI. Simply add another email handler to trigger an email to the submission author when some element value changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions folks, I'm getting back into drupal after a long time using other CMS's.

What I am really looking for is the ability to add a comment thread to each submission. This way the admins can have a conversation without having to use another application like discord to do so.

But I'm not entirely sure if it's possible with Maestro I could use $form and include a comment type that way? after the accept/Reject buttons are added